# What is the purpose of gradle-wrapper.properties in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my gradle-wrapper.properties to 2.10 from 2.8. But I want to know that what its purpose in Android Studio. As we didn't see any gradle-wrapper properties in eclipse.

Comment: may be this documentation  help you.. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gradle Wrapper** is a type batch or shell script that downloads and automatically configures Gradle to execute tasks. Imagine that you want to run a Gradle build, well you need to download and install Gradle in your computer, so this concept allows is to distribute our project and build configurations with no need to have Gradle installed.

Also their official *gradle* [webiste](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) says :

> Most tools require installation on your computer before you can use
>   them. If the installation is easy, you may think that’s fine. But it
>   can be an unnecessary burden on the users of the build. Equally
>   importantly, will the user install the right version of the tool for
>   the build? What if they’re building an old version of the software?
>   The Gradle Wrapper solves both these problems and is the preferred way
>   of starting a Gradle build.

Comment: Amir Thanks for the answer, Now i got the idea :)